# python3 global name 'SOL_SOCKET is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

when I use `gevent`, I can not use `requests`, is my useage wrong?

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import gevent, requests
requests.get('https://haofly.net')
```

it raise the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
  return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
  self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
  conn.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 289, in connect
  ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
  return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 60, in wrap_socket
  _context=self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 143, in __init__
  if sock.getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE) != SOCK_STREAM:
NameError: global name 'SOL_SOCKET' is not defined
```

The version of my Python is 3.3

If I add `ssl=False` to `monkey.patch_all()`, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 352, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 831, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 289, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 245, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 335, in __init__
    server_hostname)
TypeError: _wrap_socket() argument 1 must be _socket.socket, not SSLSocket
```

Comment: Interesting. That name would have been found on the `ssl` module and imported. I see Python 3.3 is supported; what version of openssl do you have installed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters 
you mean the linux package openssl? my openssl is openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6_8.1.x86_64, CentOS 6.8

Comment: The issue is that apparently `from ssl import SOL_SOCKET` fails for your installation. Why that is I don't fully understand. Perhaps you have a shadow `ssl` module somewhere? `import ssl; print(ssl.__file__)` should print a system location, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when `import ssl; print(ssl.__file__)`, it says the location,but `cat /usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py | grep SOL_SOCKET` return nothing, there is no `SQL_SOCKET` in my ssl.py, how it happend

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I found that my install package of my 3.3 contain ssl.py, but it do not contain the `SOL_SOCKET`, but I download it from `http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tar.xz`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it's the python version which cause the error. I install Python3.5, and it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a bug in gevent. It is trying to import a [`socket` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#constants) from the `ssl` library.

That specific constant *happens* to be imported into the `ssl` library because that library makes use of it. But it is only there because a fix for [issue 19422](http://bugs.python.org/issue19422) required it to be imported in to the `ssl` module. The fix for that bug was included in Python 3.3.4, and you have version 3.3.3 and you thus don't have that specific constant available in the `ssl` module as well.

You could just fix it by adding `from socket import SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE` in `gevent/_ssl3.py` (located in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages` directory on your system). Or you can upgrade to Python 3.3.4 or newer.

I've filed this as [issue #856](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/856) with the `gevent` project.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Python 3.5 version can fix this problem.